# Run Python interpreter after loading module/package

Tags: python

`python -i <module>` provides us the Python shell (aka, interpreter) right after reading *module*; whatever defined inside *module* is available at the Shell (`__main__`) namespace.
So we can do the following:

```
$ cat > mod.py << EOF
var = 'Hi'
EOF
$ python -i mod.py
>>> print(var)
Hi
>>>
```

The same works for a package:

```
$ mkdir pkg
$ cat > pkg/__main__.py << EOF
var = 'Hello'
EOF
$ python -i pkg
>>> print(var)
Hello
>>>
```

**Question**: Is there a way to have an executable module (or package) providing the same functionality? *I.e.*, some way to run the interpreter *with* the definitions previously done in the module (or package).

Edit:

- By *executable module* I mean a simple executable file:

```
$ chmod +x mod.py
$ ./mod.py
>>> print(var)
Hi
```

Comment: What do you mean by "self-executable module"?

Comment: Do you mean something like `from mod import *` ?

Comment: Right @Code-Apprentice, it was unnecessary/confusing. I edited to leave only _executable module_.

Comment: @Brandt I'm still unclear how what you are asking is different than your first example.

Comment: Sorry @Code-Apprentice, all I wanted was to get rid of the interpreter call, _i.e._, `python -i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the interpreter inside the module, it will have the definitions provided at the module if you pass it to the interpreter as `local=` keyword argument,

Just put `import code; code.interact(local=locals())` where
you want the interpreter to execute.

Here is a example of defining a variable and the running the interpreter. See that the variable is available inside the interpreter.

```
python3 -c 'import code; foo=10; code.interact(local=locals())'
Python 3.7.3 (default, May 11 2019, 00:45:16) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> foo
10
```

This will start a interpreter inside the script, is a inverted form of `python -i`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's simpler than I thought. After a glass of water I got it: [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))!

A module:

```
$ cat > mod.py << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env python -i
var = 'Chao'
EOF
$ chmod +x mod.py
$ ./mod.py
>>> print(var)
Chao
>>>
```

A [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html):

```
$ cat > modz.py << EOF
var = 'Oi'
EOF
$ python -m zipapp modz.py -o mod.pyz -p '/usr/bin/env python -i'
$ ./mod.pyz
>>> print(var)
Oi
>>>
```

---

Edit:

- Complementing with the answer from [gecos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58531316/687896), we could do that through the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) library:

```
$ cat > gecos.py << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env python
import code
var = 'Hallo'
code.interact(local=locals())
EOF
$ chmod +x gecos.py
$ ./gecos.py
>>> print(var)
Hallo
>>>
```